# How to add json result to @html.Actionlink

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

How can I get the result of data[i].NPI inside @html.Actionlink ?

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id = data[i].NPI;
    $("#records_table").append('<tr><td>' +
       data[i].DEA + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].Life_Hosp + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].NPI + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].LIC + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].License_Type + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].LastName + '</td><td>' +
       '@Html.ActionLink("CODE HERE","  ")' +       '</td></tr>'
    )
}
```

Comment: `@Html.ActionLink()` is server side code. If you want a link, then create it manually

Comment: By creating manually you mean creating an <a> tag and passing the data[i].npi to the href?

Comment: Yes. If your controller and action names are fixed, you can define the 'base' url using `var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("..", "..")';` before the loop, and inside the loop append any route/query string values to build the `href` value

Comment: Html.ActionLink just creates an a-tag, since this is client side just create one and add whatever href and text you wan't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to deal with this is to render a template link, with placeholder parameters on the server, then do a replacement on the client. I can't provide working code, since there isn't much to go on, but something like this should get you started...

```
var templateUrl = '@Url.Action("Controller", "Action", new { id = "#REPLACEME#" })';
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var id = data[i].NPI;
    $("#records_table").append('<tr><td>' +
       data[i].DEA + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].Life_Hosp + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].NPI + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].LIC + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].License_Type + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].FirstName + '</td><td>' +
       data[i].LastName + '</td><td>' +
       '<a href="' + templateUrl.replace('#REPLACEME#', data[i].NPI) +
       '">Anchor Text</a></td></tr>';
    )
}
```

Basically, you use `Url.Action` to create your URL with a fake ID. You render this value into the Javascript so that the template URL will be delivered to the client and made available to the browser as a string constant. When the Javascript runs in the browser, you can replace the fake ID with the real deal. This will give you a fully functional action URL. Then you merely need to put the URL into an anchor, button, or whatever you want to accomplish here.